# I want to subtract the value of 'percent' from the function by 0.25 in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to subtract the value of 'percent' from the function by 0.25.

However, subtraction does not work.

I used setState, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useCallback} from 'react';

const Ques = () => {
const [percent,setPercent] = useState(1);
const intervalRef = useRef(null);

const start = useCallback(() =>{
    if (intervalRef.current !== null){
      return;
    }
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(()=>{
      if (percent > 0){ 
        setPercent(c => c - 0.25);
        console.log("percent = ", percent);
  
      }
      else {
        setPercent(c => 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
          <button onClick={()=>{start()}}>{"Start"}</button>
      </div>
  );
}
export default Ques;
```

Comment: Just wanted to share an observation: `setPercent(c => 1);` may be simplified as `setPercent(1);`. Also, just above the `<button>`, would you please add `{percent}` - so, it will be rendered on the UI. Please share your feedback on what happens when `percent` is rendered on the UI - does it change?

Comment: Subtraction is operated on 'button', but 'percent=1' is continuously output on the console. And setPercent(1); does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `ref` for percent also and chenge its `current` value as:

[`codesandbox link`](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-tree-zc4pik?file=/src/Ques.js)

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback } from "react";

const Ques = () => {
  const percentRef = useRef(1);
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  const start = useCallback(() => {
    if (intervalRef.current !== null) {
      return;
    }
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("percent = ", percentRef.current);
      percentRef.current > 0
        ? (percentRef.current -= 0.25)
        : (percentRef.current = 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Ques;
```

Comment: link to article is broken

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

The enqueued state updates are working correctly but you've a stale enclosure over the `percent` state in the interval callback that you are logging, it never will update.

## Solution

If you want to log the `percent` state then use an `useEffect` hook to log changes.

```
const Ques = () => {
  const [percent, setPercent] = useState(1);
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("percent = ", percent); // <-- log state changes here
  }, [percent]);

  const start = useCallback(() => {
    if (intervalRef.current !== null) {
      return;
    }
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setPercent((c) => Math.max(0, c - 0.25)); // <-- simpler updater function
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Percent: {percent * 100}
      <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit i-want-to-subtract-the-value-of-percent-from-the-function-by-0-25-in-react]

Answer (score 1):

I think `useCallback` and `useRef` is not a good fit. Below is a minimal verifiable example using `useState` and `useEffect`. Note this function appropriately performs [cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) on the timer when the component is unmounted. Click <kbd>Run</kbd> to run the code snippet and click <kbd>start</kbd> to begin running the effect.

```js
function App() {
  const [percent, setPercent] = React.useState(1)
  const [running, setRunning] = React.useState(false)
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!running) return
    const t = window.setTimeout(() => {
      setPercent(c => c > 0 ? c - 0.25 : 1)
    }, 1000)
    return () => window.clearTimeout(t)
  }, [running, percent])
  
  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => setRunning(true)} children="start" />
    <pre>percent: {percent}</pre>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be one possible solution to achieve what is presumed to be the desired objective:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState, useRef, useCallback} = React;

const Ques = () => {
  const [percent,setPercent] = useState(1);
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  const start = useCallback((flag) => {
      if (intervalRef.current !== null){
        if (flag && flag === 'end') clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
        return;
      }
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setPercent(
          prev => (prev > 0 ? prev - 0.25 : 1)
        );
      }, 1000);

    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
          percent: {percent} <br/> <br/>
          <button onClick={() => start('bgn')}>Start</button> &emsp;
          <button onClick={() => start('end')}>Stop</button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h3>DEMO</h3>
    <Ques />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('rd')
);
```

```html
<div id='rd' />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

- There are two buttons `Start` and `Stop`
- Both invoke the same `start` method, but with different params (`flag`)
- If `intervalRef` is already set (ie, not null) and `flag` is `end`, clear the interval
- The `percent` is added to the UI to see real-time changes to its value
- `setPercent` is modified to use `prev` (which holds the correct state)

Comment: `console.log` always shows `percent: 1`.

Comment: Yes, my intention was to show the difference between rendering a state variable on the UI.

Comment: There's no second argument to `setPercent`, so the placement of the `console.log` looks like a typo.

Comment: Have removed the console. Thank you both !